# Tailwind CSS "sm:block" class is not overwriting "hidden" class after passing the "sm:" breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsive, tailwind-css

I am following a navbar tutorial from the creator of TailwindCSS on Youtube and I am stuck on [this part](https://youtu.be/qrTsS3z8BAw?t=43), where the  `sm:block` class should override the `hidden` class when the screen width hits the `sm:` breakpoint.

[This almost exactly the same example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zpW7kLkvp6) works as expected, where the items show when the page's width is increased.

However, when I try to implement this on my project which is created using  `npx create-next-app --example blog-starter-typescript`. [This is where I got it from](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter-typescript), the items on the navbar don't show when the page width is increased.

[Here is the exact spot in my repo](https://github.com/Agile-Import/marketing/pull/1/commits/1cc1bcf4c4c6c9193c92efc0cd57d2db83ab8cf9#r532026926) where this doesn't work.

If I replace `hidden sm:block` with `sm:hidden block` it works. and if I  add a different background colour to each breakpoint, that also works.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Dark Theme for Chrome" extension has been injecting styling that had `display : hidden !important` in it. Removing that extension has resolved my issue.

I realised this after seeing the app working as expected in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` is not override correctly
try `sm:!block`

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be nice if you please make sure to provide the right and relevant answer (not assumptions) and share proper reference link behind your solution with example. Thank you for your contribution.